# incorrect syntax near begin expecting external for alter procedure

Tags: sql-server

I have a script file which does lot DDL Operations - it all included as part of the Transaction but I am getting an Error at the Begin statement of Alter Procedure as "incorrect syntax near begin expecting external" - is there any way to put the Alter Procedure as part of the Transaction Script? Here is my Script for it:

```
USE XXXXXX;
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    DROP INDEX IF EXISTS [IX_NOVId] ON [dbo].[Violations]

    PRINT N'Altering [dbo].[OneToManies]...';
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OneToManies] ALTER COLUMN [ChildEntity] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL;
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OneToManies] ALTER COLUMN [ParentEntity] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL;


    PRINT N'Altering [dbo].[usp_Report_ClosedReports]...';
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Report_ClosedReports]
        @EnforcementSectionId INT,
        @IsPreCase            VARCHAR(3) = NULL,
        @FromDate             DATE = '01/01/2017',
        @ToDate               DATE = '01/01/2018'

    AS
         BEGIN
         DECLARE @IsPreCaseBool Bit;
         SET @IsPreCaseBool = CASE WHEN @IsPreCase = '0' THEN 0 ELSE
                              CASE WHEN @IsPreCase = '1' THEN 1 ELSE null END END;

         SELECT
            ReferenceNumber,
            CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), CaseStartDate, 101) AS CaseStartDate,
            CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), DateCreated, 101) AS DateCreated,
            CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), DateUpdated, 101) AS DateUpdated,

            CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), StatuteOfLimitationsDate, 101) AS StatuteOfLimitationsDate,       

            ApplicablePenalties,
            InvestigatorFullName,
            ContactName,
            CompanyCity,
            CompanyZip,
            CaseStatus,
            EnforcementSectionName,
            ISNULL(ViolationsCount, 0) AS ViolationsCount,
            Program
        FROM (SELECT cs.CaseId,
                        (CASE
                             WHEN [cst].IsPreCase = 1
                             THEN 'I'
                             ELSE 'C'
                         END) + dbo.CIntToChar([cs].CaseId, 5) AS ReferenceNumber,
                        [cs].CaseStartDate,
                        [cs].DateCreated,
                        [cs].DateUpdated,
                        [cs].StatuteOfLimitationsDate,
                        [cs].ApplicablePenalties,
                        inv.FirstName +' '+inv.LastName AS InvestigatorFullName,
                        ISNULL([cnt].FirstName, '')+' '+ISNULL([cnt].LastName, '') AS ContactName,
                        [cnt].Address_City AS CompanyCity,
                        [cnt].Address_Zip AS CompanyZip,
                        [cst].CaseStatusName AS CaseStatus,
                        [ens].EnforcementSectionName,
                        vl.ViolationsCount,
                        [PROG].Program
                 FROM Cases AS [cs]
                      JOIN vw_CasePrograms AS PROG ON PROG.CaseId = [cs].CaseId
                      LEFT JOIN CaseAssignedToInvestigators ctoi ON ctoi.CaseId = cs.CaseId
                      LEFT JOIN Contacts AS [cnt] ON [cnt].ContactId = [cs].CaseCompanyId
                      LEFT JOIN CaseStatus AS [cst] ON [cst].CaseStatusId = [cs].CaseStatusId


                      LEFT JOIN (select Id, UG.GroupId, FirstName, LastName 
                                 from AspNetUsers  AS U
                                 join UserGroup AS UG on UG.UserId = U.Id)  
                                    AS inv ON  (inv.Id = ctoi.UserId  AND CST.IsPreCase <> 1)--AND INV.GroupId = 10)
                                             OR (inv.Id = cs.AssignedToInspectorId AND cst.IsPreCase = 1)-- only on investigation


                      LEFT JOIN EnforcementSections AS [ens] ON [ens].EnforcementSectionId = [cs].EnforcementSectionId
                      LEFT JOIN  (
                             SELECT COUNT(1) AS ViolationsCount,
                                    v.CaseId
                             FROM dbo.Violations v
                             GROUP BY v.CaseId
                      ) vl ON vl.CaseId = cs.CaseId
                 WHERE([cst].IsPreCase = @IsPreCaseBool
                       OR @IsPreCaseBool IS NULL)
                      AND [cst].IsCaseClosed = 1                  
                      AND [cs].DateUpdated BETWEEN @FromDate and @ToDate
                      AND [cs].EnforcementSectionId = @EnforcementSectionId) AS QR
        GROUP BY 
            ReferenceNumber,
            CaseStartDate,
            DateCreated,
            DateUpdated,
            StatuteOfLimitationsDate,
            ApplicablePenalties,
            InvestigatorFullName,
            ContactName,
            CompanyCity,
            CompanyZip,
            CaseStatus,
            EnforcementSectionName,
            ViolationsCount,
            Program
        END;

    PRINT N'Altering [dbo].[SP_ViolationTypesBranched]...';

    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_ViolationTypesBranched]
        (@Types as NVARCHAR(max) = '',
        @Search AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = '')
    AS 
    BEGIN
        select 
             BranchId
            ,BranchName
            ,ViolationTypeName
            ,BranchViolationName
            ,ViolationTypeCode
            ,ViolationTypeId
            ,ViolationTypeSortOrder
            ,UploadedPhotographCategoryGroup
            ,Id = null
            --Sections

        FROM (
            select 
                VT.BranchId,
                BR.Name AS BranchName,
                BR.Name + ' - ' + ViolationTypeName AS BranchViolationName,
                ViolationTypeName,          
                ViolationTypeCode,
                VT.ViolationTypeId,
                ViolationTypeSortOrder ,
                UploadedPhotographCategoryGroup,
                (SELECT 
                    ES.EnforcementSectionName + ', ' 
                 FROM EnforcementSections AS ES 
                 WHERE ES.BranchId = VT.BranchId 
                 FOR XML PATH('')) AS Sections
            from BranchViolationTypes AS VT
            JOIN Branches       AS BR ON BR.BranchId = VT.BranchId
            --JOIN EnforcementSections AS FS ON FS.BranchId = BR.BranchId
            JOIN ViolationTypes AS VV ON VV.ViolationTypeId = VT.ViolationTypeId
        ) AS X
        WHERE dbo.DynoSearch(
            ISNULL(CAST(X.BranchName        AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),'') + 
            ISNULL(CAST(X.ViolationTypeCode AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),'') + 
            ISNULL(CAST(X.ViolationTypeName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),'') + 
            ISNULL(CAST(x.Sections          AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),''), 
        @Search) = 1


    END

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ViolationTypeNOVs] WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.ViolationTypeNOVs_dbo.ViolationTypes_ViolationTypeId];
    PRINT N'Update complete.';  

    ROLLBACK TRAN -- Transaction Success!
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRAN --RollBack in case of Error

    -- you can Raise ERROR with RAISEERROR() Statement including the details of the exception
    RAISERROR(ERROR_MESSAGE(), ERROR_SEVERITY(), 1)
END CATCH
```

Any help please? Thank you.

Comment: To start, `ALTER PROCEDURE` must be the only statement in a batch.

Comment: Side note: You roll back at the end of the `TRY` block. That's probably not what you intended.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have BEGIN TRY and BEGIN CATCH around batches.you can use the last batch to check that all previous steps have succeeded (by examining the catalog views like sys.objects for example). Then you can decide if the batch all succeeded and either commit or roll back.

I think you should write like this:

```
Begin transaction ....

...
Print N’any think that you like’;
Go

Alter procedure ....
...
```